# using AZCOPY with only connectionstring

Tags: azure, azcopy

I am provided with only a 'connection string' for azcopy.

```
Connectionstring: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=someaccoutname;AccountKey=someaccountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
URL: https://someaccoutname.blob.core.windows.net/somename
```

I do not have a 'sas' token or access to the azure portal to create a sas token'.

How can I use AZCOPY to sync a folder on a VM, to that azure storage account, with only the connection string.

Comment: If you mean sync blobs recursively to a storage blob container using AzCopy, you could use `az storage azcopy blob sync --container --source --connection-string`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/storage-preview/storage/azcopy/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_storage_preview_az_storage_azcopy_blob_sync).

Comment: @Aflred please share if you got the answer i am having the same problem

Comment: @PamelaPeng-MSFT, that flag doesnt exist on `azcopy`. Its `az` exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Use Azure Storage Explorer to download the SAS needed. Download and install it [from here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/).

When it opens, connect to your storage account using the connection string, navigate to the container and keep it selected in the left containers pane.

Bottom left -> change from Properties tab to Actions -> Get Shared Access Signature (that's SAS)

Set the expiry date/time, check on permissions you'll need. (Add, Write etc if you want to upload something, probably Delete as well if you want to over-write older files). Create.

Copy the URL. This will be your destination string, with the SAS included.

Note: if there's a $ sign in it, replace with "%24" - at least for linux that seems to be required.

Now form your azcopy command (uploading a folder here)

```
azcopy copy --from-to=LocalBlob "localfolder/" "destination-with-sas" --recursive
```

Comment: The same thing works with the online Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

That is simple.

The connection string has 2 information you need.
[account] = someaccoutname
[acesskey] = somthing like this 2iusdofiausd98273412934213/fsdf23409237409dfoasihdfasir9028742hvhxczoivhsadfSFAOIf34Jq==

```
azcopy cp https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/folder/subfolder/file.txt?[accesskey from connection string, it ends with ==] c:\temp\
```

Comment: Will it work ? i think the SAS token start with something like azcopy cp https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/folder/subfolder/file.txt?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-12-30T23:08:26Z&st=2020-12-29T15:08:26Z&spr=https,http&sig=a-valid-sgnature-key c:\temp\

Comment: Well it works for me. And I checked before posting. Did you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work with azcopy 10: "failed to perform copy command due to error: Login Credentials missing. No SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `az storage container generate-sas` to generate the SAS token, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/generate-sas-tokens